# What is accidental macro substitution?

Tags: c++, coding-style

What is accidental macro substitution?

In [Vera++](https://bitbucket.org/ThArGos/vera) C++ linter, rule T016 states:

> The calls to min and max functions should be protected against
>   accidental macro substitution.
>
> ```
> x = max(y, z); // wrong, vulnerable to accidental macro substitution
>
> x = (max)(y, z); // OK
>
> x = max BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION (y, z); // OK
> ```

Why is this a good rule, and what is so special about min and max functions that require this rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accidental macro substitution is unintentional use of a macro whose name conflicts with a function.

The situation Vera++'s checks are designed to prevent occurs when misbehaved system headers — most famously `<windows.h>` — define `min` and `max` macros that interfere with application-defined functions of the same name or even with standard library functions such as [`std::min<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/), [`std::max<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/), and [`std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/). (Other names have been known to cause clashes as well.)

Since macros are not namespace-aware, invoking the functions as **`std`**`::min(...)` doesn't help because `min` is still expanded by the preprocessor. To work around this issue, such functions must be invoked as `(function)(args...)`, which will prevent macroexpansion provided it is defined as `#define function(arg1, arg2) ...`, as is typically the case with `min` and `max`. Another available option is to `#undef` them before usage, but after including the misbehaving header. Boost provides its own substitution prevention marker, although its self-descriptiveness is offset by the clutter it introduces.

If you control inclusion of `<windows.h>`, you can also `#define NOMINMAX` prior to its inclusion, which will instruct `windows.h` not to define the `min` and `max` macros.

Comment: +1. Totally unrelated to what I originally thought the question was. There are a few others of these besides min and max, as I recall.

Comment: BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION is just "#define BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION" (it doesn't have any value defined). It's unreadable only because they choose a descriptive name for the macro.

Comment: `#define NOMINMAX` helps as well.

Comment: @NicholasWilson It's a reasonable choice on their side as it makes the usage of the macro self-documenting. But as it also adds a huge amount of clutter, and (f)(...) is a known idiom, I would choose the latter. The Vera++ lint has no preference either way.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. You implied in your answer it was an unreadable approach, and I was saying they at least had a good reason for it (being descriptive). The point I was trying to make though is that boost's "own substitution mechanism" is actually very simple, just an empty macro.

Comment: @NicholasWilson I've now toned down the sentence in the answer to better reflect the tradeoff.

Comment: Just define `NOMINMAX` in the project settings. No need to have control over what gets included where.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Assuming you have control over project settings, yes. (`-DNOMINMAX` would be the Unix equivalent.) But when writing a library that uses templates (think Boost), most of your code can be in the headers, and you don't control the project settings of the final application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that nasty libraries (or stupid programmers) will commonly define max and min macros that you might not expect. If your code is assuming evaluation will be done by a nice function, you'll get incorrect results (or even undefined behaviour). The linter is being helpful by pointing out that, unless you're really sure you know all the macros defined by all the includes you're using, it's safer not to run the risk of clashing with such common macro names.